# cudaError_t 1 : "__global__ function call is not configured" returned from 'cublasCreate(&handle_)'

Tags: gpu, kaldi, nvidia-titan

I run ASR experiment using Kaldi on SGE cluster consisting of two workstation with TITAN XP.
And randomly I meet the following problem:

> ERROR (nnet3-train[5.2.62~4-a2342]:FinalizeActiveGpu():cu-device.cc:217) cudaError_t 1 : "__global__ function call is not configured" returned from 'cublasCreate(&handle_)'

I guess something is wrong with GPU driver or hardware.

Could you please offer some help?

[And here is the complete log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hp6B.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue in running darknet in one of the TX2

with reference to

https://blog.csdn.net/JIEJINQUANIL/article/details/103091537

enter the root by

```
sudo su
```

Then source the catkin_ws

Then launch the darkent.

Then can run.

[image]

Here is my result

[image]

Hope you can solve it by similar method